# What kind of part is this?

Tags: pcb, pcb-assembly

What kind of part on the board below? Or it's a part of another part?

[image]

Comment: looks like an extractor lever .....  most likely,  it operates a latching mechanism and is used for pulling the module out of the device that the module is installed in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an AMC (Advanced Mezzanine Card) hot swap ejector handle.

Similar to [one of these](https://www.southco.com/static/Literature/p7-amc.en.pdf).

There are three positions the latch can be in, a switch to tell the card that withdrawal is anticipated, and typically an indicator that indicates when it is safe to remove the card. Images from [here](http://www.atd-elektronik.cz/file_get.php?id=13021&type=db).

[image]